# Customizing a 3D Plotly Visualization with a slider bar

Tags: matlab, contour, plotly

I've been exploring Plotly recently. I've made a contourslice of a 3D Value function using the Plotly MATLAB API's fig2plotly(). However, I've been researching how to further customize the plot, and I can't figure out how exactly I'd go about doing this.

**My current plot is here:**
https://plot.ly/~txizzle/81
It's basically different contours stacked on top of each other.

**My goals:**
I'd like to add a slider bar that will show just one contour slice at a time (maybe by changing visibility). Ideally, I could fix an eagle-eye view from the top, so moving the slider will make it appear as if the plot is 2D.

**My thoughts on how to approach this:**
1) https://plot.ly/javascript-graphing-library/range-slider/ seems to be an HTML/JS implementation of a custom slider bar that changes the x-axis range of a line chart. From what I've read, this approach seems to be Node.js only. Ideally, I'd like to implement something in just HTML/JS/JQuery/D3.js.
2) Alternatively, I could use a 2D contour plot instead of a 3D contourslice:
https://plot.ly/49/~txizzle/
However, now, I will need to have many of these contour plots. I'm not sure how I would switch between different contour plots with a slider.

My Questions:
1) How do I customize Plotly plots? Is this possible without relying on Node.js? I don't want to just embed the plots using Plotly's given auto-embedder, because it abstracts everything away.
2) Should I do a contourslice or many different contour plots?
3) How do I add a slider bar to switch the visibility of different contour slices, or how do I add a slider bar to switch different plots entirely?

Thank you for your time! Looking forward to explore Plotly more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you used the MATLAB library to generate the plotly figure, you can add slider effects by embedding the plotly figure as an iframe in an offline HTML doc, then using Plotly's postmessage API.

Here's an example:
https://plot.ly/matlab/range-slider/

postMessage API:
https://github.com/plotly/postMessage-API